# Get the first value of an array of hash with Perl

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

I have a subroutine that executes an SQL query and returns the result as a reference to an array of hashes.

```
my $value = query("SELECT value from table WHERE foo=bar LIMIT 1");
```

How can I extract the first value from the only hash, without having to know the key of the element?

Comment: Please note that the idea of "the first value from the hash" is not valid.  Hashes are not ordered.  The keys of the hash are not ordered.  Therefore, there is no "first value".

Comment: DBI has [selectcol_arrayref](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#selectcol_arrayref) and [selectrow_arrayref](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#selectrow_arrayref) for just this situation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you knew the key, it would be

```
query("...")->[0]{$key}
```

But you don't know the key, so we'll have to grab it. The problem is the elements of a hash aren't ordered. You can grab *a key*, but there's no such thing as *the first key*. But it looks like you only have one element in the hash, so the following will do the trick:

```
my ($val) = values(%{ query("...")->[0] });
  -or-
my $val = ( values(%{ query("...")->[0] }) )[0];
  -or-
my $val = ( %{ query("...")->[0] } )[1];
```

This is all just addressing the symptoms. Your problem stems from the fact that you are using yet-another-stupid-DBI-wrapper<sup>[1]</sup>. Without your wrapper you could simply do

```
my ($val) = $dbh->selectrow_array("...");
```

---

1. Why does everyone insist on writing wrappers that make it harder to access the database? If you want to make DB access earlier, don't create a interface that simply executes SQL statements — DBI already does that quite well — create an interface that performs specific tasks (e.g. `get_x_for_y($dbh, $y)`).

Comment: Sorry to insist but how can I rewrite `$ref->[0]{$key}` `$ref->[0][1]`

Comment: @coin: I am guessing that you are coming to Perl from PHP, where arrays are a combination of ordered values, like a Perl array, and keyed lookup, like a Perl hash.  But in Perl, the idea of "the first value from the hash" is not valid.  Hashes are not ordered.  The keys of the hash are not ordered.  Therefore, there is no "first value".  You cannot rewrite `$ref->[0]{$key}` as `$ref->[0][1]`.

Comment: Updated to simplify solution

Comment: @AndyLester, Maybe, but `( %{ $ref->[0] } )[1]` isn't too far from `$ref->[0][1]`, syntactically speaking. (It doesn't have the implied efficiency of `$ref->[0][1]`, though.)